# Magento 2 getUrl is generating a different security key

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, url

I am trying to generate the following url, in the adminhtml area:

```
$this->url->getUrl('adminhtml/system_config/edit', ['section' => 'mysection']);
// where $this->url is an instance of \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
```

and the url is being generated correctly.

The only thing is that another security key is being generated as part of the url (I'm getting "Invalid security or form key. Please refresh the page." on the next page after I click the generated link).

How can I preserve the current key?

Comment: If you are creating admin URL link, try using `Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface` class.

Comment: this solved my problem. you should add this comment as an answer and I'll be happy to approve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue with your approach is that you are using `Magento\Framework\UrlInterface` to create admin url. Magento has a separate Interface defined for Backend urls.

Please use `Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface` class to generate your URL with correct secret key.

Comment: Thanks for this! I would add that if you do **not** want the secret key part appended to the URL as I needed, you can then use the turnOffSecretKey() method